# How to make sure that sections with no rows are not displayed

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have an indexed table view just like the contacts list in iphone.

I want that if a section has no rows then the section header for that section should not be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u use array for each section then u can checkout by that array count to 0 or not

if 0 then that returns 0 height for header

```
    -(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{



        if ([urSectionArray count]>0) {

            return 90;

        }
        return 0;


    }
```

more details

http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=240

Answer (score 0):

Why not make `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` return zero in this case?